# How to store multiple values on shared preferences and does not override for previous values in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When i will store multiple values store on shared prefrences and store only one data then latest store on data then override for latest data instead of old data because old data kindly flush then what i will do, thanks in advanace.

```
    mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("multipledata",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    mEditor.putString("PACKAGE", toastMessage);
    mEditor.putLong("TIME", curTime);
    mEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the different keys for different data 
like
PAKAGE1    TIME1
PAKAGE2     TIME2
PAKAGE3    TIME3

with the help of loops.

Comment: Brajendra Pandey : thanks dear, its working fine with different keys.

Comment: @BrajendraPandey While retrieving, Now would I know the exact number of records available? that is, it may be till PACKAGE4 or may be PACKAGE12